# How to work around pointer casting in C to avoid unaligned memory access?

Tags: c, casting, undefined-behavior

I recently learned that pointer casting could trigger unaligned memory access, such as in

```
void test_func(uint8_t *data) {
        /*The rest of the code removed for clarity*/
    uint32_t value = *((uint32_t *) data);
}
```

But how can I work around it, if I really need to cast pointers? In the example above, what if I have to access `data` as an `uint32_t` but still want to avoid unaligned memory access?

Comment: `uint32_t value; memcpy(&value, data, sizeof value);`

Comment: simple do not use pointer punning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to work around pointer casting in C to avoid unaligned memory access?

You can't (e.g. on x86-64 unaligned memory access are possible, but slow; it might also be the case on [Arduino](https://arduino.cc/)-s).

See also [`_Alignas`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) and [`_Alignof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof) operators of C11.

On many implementations, a pointer can be casted back and forth from `intptr_t` and you could then play bitwise tricks.

> In the example above, what if I have to access `data` as an `uint32_t` but still want to avoid unaligned memory access?

You need to ensure that the *caller* of `test_func` is passing a well aligned pointer.

You could be helped by tools like [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com), the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or perhaps, at end of spring 2021, [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/)

You might `#include <assert.h>` and add, as the first statement of your `test_func` : `assert((intptr_t)data % sizeof(uint32_t) == 0);` ; see e.g. [assert(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html).

Comment: The last assertion: `(intptr_t)data % sizeof(uint32_t) == 0` can be overly restrictive.  An implementation could have alignment requirements for `uint32_t` of only 2 or 1.  Consider a 16-bit or 8-bit embedded processor.  I do not see "bitwise tricks" leading to a good alignment test.  Noel.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could I conclude that pointer casting in C is inherently problematic and should be avoided to ensure code portability and reliability?

Comment: @zell: One of the strengths of C is that almost all implementations can support a wide range of constructs that might not be practical to support on 100% of implementations and are thus not mandated by the Standard.  Some compiler writers who aren't interested in selling compilers treat the Standard's failure to mandate support for a construct as an intention to characterize as "broken" any code that would use it, but the authors of the Standard have expressly said that they used the phrase "Undefined Behavior" to identify "areas of conforming language extension".

Answer (score 3):

> How to work around pointer casting ... to avoid unaligned memory access?

Use `memcpy(&value, data, sizeof value);` to transfer the data instead of `*((uint32_t *) data)`.  A good compiler will emit efficient code.

```
uint8_t data[4] = { 1,2,3,4};
uint32_t value;
memcpy(&value, data, sizeof value);
```

... or insure the `uint8_t value[]` is aligned with a `union`,  `alignas` via `*alloc()`

```
union {
  uint8_t data[4];
  uint32_t d32;
} x;
...  
test_func(x.data) {

#include <stdalign.h>
alignas(uint32_t) uint8_t data[4] = { 1,2,3,4};
test_func(data);

uint8_t *data = malloc(sizeof *data * 4);
...
test_func(data);
free(data);
```

Comment: When targeting platforms that enforce alignment requirements, code which efficiently processes 32-bit data won't work with unaligned addresses, and code which works correctly with unaligned addresses will be sub-optimal when addresses happen to be aligned.  When using clang, if arguments to `memcpy` are pointers to types that require 32-bit alignment, it will generate code that efficiently handles aligned arguments, but fails with unaligned arguments.